# Checkbox and Radio button problems with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to develop an online examination tool for my work. I have a class that defines an exam that contains a list of Questions, a class for Question that contains a list of Answers, and a class for Answer. I have a view model that pulls out the list of questions and passes it to the view as well as an array of ints to hold the value of the answer for each question. In the view, I loop through the questions, and in each question I loop through each possible answer. For multiple choice, this is easy. I just use:

```
<input asp-for="SelectedAnswer[q]" type="radio" value="@a" />@Model.Questions[q].answers[a].AnswerText
```

This works great, it passes the SelectedAnswer int array back the the controller on submit and I can do whatever I want with it. My problem comes down to if the question requires a checkboxlist for multiple right answers. I obviously cant use the same int array to post back the answer, so I hought about creating a second bool array for each of the checkboxes in a question and send that back. But this only really works for one question as each new question overrides the bool array on postback.

What I am trying to figure out is how to do this where I have different types of questions that can be displayed on a single page, and sent back to a controller when the submit button is pressed for processing.

Maybe I need a better view model? I am not sure where to go next with this.
I can provide any of the code required, I just didnt want to fill up the entire page with code.

My view:

```
@model DSCA_Exams.Models.ExamViewModels.ExamViewModel
<form asp-action="Exam_Results">
    <div>
        @for (int q = 0; q < Model.Questions.Count(); q++)
        {
            <div>
                <hr />
                <h4>@Model.Questions[q].QuestionText</h4>
                <ul>
                    @for (int a = 0; a < Model.Questions[q].answers.Count(); a++)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @if (Model.Questions[q].QuestionType == 0)
                            {
                                <input asp-for="SelectedAnswer[q]" type="radio" value="@a" />@Model.Questions[q].answers[a].AnswerText
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <input asp-for="@Model.isSelected[a]"  />@Model.Questions[q].answers[a].AnswerText
                            }
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" value="Grade Test" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view models and preserve the object graph. For example:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerViewModel> Answers { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
{
    <p>@Model.Questions[i].QuestionText</p>

    @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count; j++)
    {
        <label>
            <input asp-for="Questions[i].SelectedAnswers" type="radio" value="@Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].Id" />
            @Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].AnswerText
        </label>
    }
}
```

Then, when you post, the modelbinder will be able to preserve the object graph and you can inspect the `SelectAnswers` property of each question.

Comment: I added my current view to the question. I am doing what you suggested more or less. I am not having an issue with radio buttons, but more with chckboxlist for more then one question. I cant do a multi-dimension array to hold up to n answers per question, so I dont know how to pass multiple checkbox lists worth of values back to the controller.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Instead of trying to compact all the answers to all the questions into one array. Instead, have each question have it's own array of selected answers. In the case of multiple choice, there would just be one item, but in the case of a checkbox list, you'd have multiple items. No multidimensional arrays necessary.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know you could do that. Thats where I struggle with asp.net. I can code c# for days, but all of this automagic stuff with asp.net is hard for me. Ill give that a shot.

Comment: Ok, so I did what you said, and I am running into a different issue with the same part. If I make the list of selectedanswers an int list, the radio button questions work great but the checkbox questions throw an error saying they have to be boolean. If I do booleans, then the radio button questions dont work right but the checkbox question do. Should I just do 2 lists with a flag for question type, and have it populate the right list for the right question? Or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Well that worked! What I ended up doing is creating an in called SelectedAnswer and a List of booleans called SelectedAnswers. If its question of type 0 (radio) then it does stores the radio button result in the int. If its of type 1 (checkbox) then it stores each checkbox result in the boolean list. Then in my controller, I just grab the vm, check the question type flag, and compare the results to my exam model based on the int or boolean list the type flag directs to and boom, everything works great. Thanks for the guidance brother!